# Joining two table one to many relationship and then concatenate the second table into one

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables

```
users table
id  name 
1   john
2   reaper


users_bid table
id user_id amount
1   1       50
2   1       100
3   2       80
4   1       120
```

Now i want a query which will give the below result

```
id  user_id  amount
1     1       50,100,120
2     2        80
```

Comment: I hope you are not going to store *amount* in another field for further processing.

Comment: nope, if i do it then it will be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want [GROUP_CONCAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

```
select T1.id, T2.user_id, group_concat(T2.amount order by T2.amount separator ', ') as amount
from users T1
inner join users_bid T2
on T2.user_id = T1.id
group by T1.id, T2.user_id
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, i really didnot know this function

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT users.id, users_bid.user_id, users_bid.group_concat(amount) AS amount
FROM users
JOIN users_bid ON users_bid.user_id = users.id
GROUP BY users.id
```